# jumping to another activity using Thread.sleep()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i'm trying to jump from activity one to activity two but after 1 second. So i used Thread.sleep(1000) and after that the activity two comes to front.Its working good but problem is I have given a image background in activity one which is not shown.

```
 public class Activity1 extends Activity {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Intent i=new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class );
        startActivity(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

additionally I included a button in Activity two which does the functionality of jumping to Activity one, in this case the image is shown for 1 second but not the first time when I open up my app.

Comment: As I understand, you want on load start 2nd activity immediately, right?

Comment: I must be missing the point.  Are you asking how to show the background of activity 1 in activity 2?

Comment: Do **not** use `Thread.sleep()` on the main application thread, please.

Comment: @MaximShoustin yes i want to load second activity after 1 second, without and click event in Activity 1.

Comment: @Yashhy, so start 2nd Activity as Main one. Its not good practice to call 2nd Activity immediately after `onCreate`

Comment: @Simon No. Activity 1 contains an image and Activity 2 has the main content, so I want first display the image present in Activity 1 and the automatically shift to Activity 2.

Comment: @MaximShoustin I don't want to start Activity 2 at start up.

Comment: @Yashhy Hmmm, I think you have some design issue. Don't use separate Activity only to show image. You can create `RelativeLayout` and show/hide it and use 1 Activity only

Comment: It is as CommansWare suggested... Do not use Thread.sleep() in the UI thread. Create a thread, use Thread.sleep(1000) inside it, and start activity two after sleep. The image is not loading because you are interrupting the UI thread. It seems like a splash screen, use proper methods for it. But For now I suggest you create a Thread ans start it in onCreate().

Comment: @MaximShoustin is there any possibilities of hiding the image (using 'ImageView')  and after 1 second and showing the contents present in the Activity (in background) this can be done in one Activity right?

Comment: @Yashhy right, I posted some flow there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create RelativeLayout and show/hide it and use 1 Activity only

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{

 private ImageView view = ....;

 ....
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ....
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You UI is not built until after onCreate() finishes.  Therefore, if you start activity 2 in onCreate(), you will never see activity 1.

Instead:

```
@Override
void onAttachedToWindow()  {
    // start activity 2
}
```

As others have said in their comments, you should never use sleep on the UI thread.  Indeed, I  wish that Java made it much harder to use sleep because it is used far too much and often as a quick fix which avoids the right solution.

In this case, you should use an `AsyncTask` to start the second activity after one second.

Comment: **"...I wish that Java made it much harder to use sleep..."** - Agreed, I personally think that using `sleep()` is basically a hack whatever the language.

Comment: `LinearLayout line_main=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_main);
line_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.train_final);`


I have this code, the background set here should be gone after few seconds so the main content in this Activity is shown. How to do it in AsyncTask? Thanks in advance.